# Bootstrap 5 carousel to have one progressbar

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get my bootstrap 5 carousel to have a progress bar with left and right arrows and the number of slides like this one.

[image: Example]

So, because I am a javascript noob, I need a little help. I did my research and found two ways, but both of them been using bootstrap 3 and didn't work on my bootstrap 5 but finally I found a similar thread but the thing that the java script written is made to work manual per click and not automatic so technically I want the same thing but I want the numbers to have an active class and to switch from 1-2 to 2-3 and so on and I want this to be applied on the progress bar according to the slides.
[Thats the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73140584/counting-up-with-progress-bar-carousel)

I Really appreciate any help

Thats what i have currently :

```js
const myCarousel = document.getElementById("carouselExampleIndicators2");
const carouselIndicators = myCarousel.querySelectorAll(
  ".carousel-indicators button span"
);
let intervalID;

const carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel);

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  fillCarouselIndicator(1);
});

myCarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function (e) {
  let index = e.to;
  fillCarouselIndicator(++index);
});

function fillCarouselIndicator(index) {
  let i = 0;
  for (const carouselIndicator of carouselIndicators) {
    carouselIndicator.style.width = 0;
  }
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  carousel.pause();

  intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    i++;

    myCarousel.querySelector(".carousel-indicators .active span").style.width =
      i + "%";

    if (i >= 100) {
      // i = 0; -> just in case
      carousel.next();
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-item p{ 
  font-family:'Giove',sans-serif; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin:  16px 200px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #e9c8b9;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-item p::before {
  content: url(../images/vec.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 21.5%;
  opacity: 14%;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 6px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] span {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #bb440d;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid text-center section0 px-0 bg-dark">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-pause="true">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">
        <span></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">
        <span></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">
        <span></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner pb-5">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <p>The most exclusive listings in Europe and the Middle East, <br>
          carefully handpicked to deliver state-of-the-art <br>
          customer experience.</p>
          <!-- <div class="number">1</div> -->
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <p>The most exclusive listings in Europe and the Middle East, <br>
          carefully handpicked to deliver state-of-the-art <br>
          customer experience.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <p>The most exclusive listings in Europe and the Middle East, <br>
          carefully handpicked to deliver state-of-the-art <br>
          customer experience.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is what you are looking for, but I'm not sure if it is the best practice in terms of structure, but it is 100% responsive and functional.

```js
const myCarousel = document.getElementById("carouselExampleIndicators2");
const carouselIndicators = myCarousel.querySelectorAll(
  ".carousel-indicators button span"
);
let intervalID;

const carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel);

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  fillCarouselIndicator(1);
});

myCarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function (e) {
  let index = e.to;
  fillCarouselIndicator(++index);
});

function fillCarouselIndicator(index) {
  let i = 0;
  for (const carouselIndicator of carouselIndicators) {
    carouselIndicator.style.width = 0;
  }
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  carousel.pause();

  intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    i++;

    myCarousel.querySelector(".carousel-indicators .active span").style.width =
      i + "%";

    if (i >= 100) {
      // i = 0; -> just in case
      carousel.next();
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-item p{ 
  font-family:'Giove',sans-serif; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin:  16px 200px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #e9c8b9;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-item p::before {
  content: url(../images/vec.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 21.5%;
  opacity: 14%;
}


#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1.9px;
  border: 0.2px solid #e9c8b9;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators2 .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] span {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e9c8b9;
  border-radius: inherit;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid text-center section0 px-0 bg-dark">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-pause="true">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">
        <span></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">
        <span></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">
        <span></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner pb-5">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <p>The most exclusive listings in Europe and the Middle East, <br>
          carefully handpicked to deliver state-of-the-art <br>
          customer experience.</p>
          <!-- <div class="number">1</div> -->
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <p>The most exclusive listings in Europe and the Middle East, <br>
          carefully handpicked to deliver state-of-the-art <br>
          customer experience.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <p>The most exclusive listings in Europe and the Middle East, <br>
          carefully handpicked to deliver state-of-the-art <br>
          customer experience.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
```